# Connect to a backgrounded iOS app acting as a peripheral from a macOS app

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS and macOS app that make heavy use of Core Bluetooth. The core functionality of the app involves having a central device (`CBCentralManager`) connect to a peripheral device (`CBPeripheralManager`), retrieve some data, then disconnect. Either device, whether macOS or iOS can act as either a central or peripheral depending on who needs the data.

At first I thought there was an issue with my code, but after testing the app with two iOS devices, one is able to connect and extract data from the peripheral device even when the peripheral device is locked and the app is in the background. Now according to the [docs concerning background advertising on iOS under "The bluetooth-peripheral Background Execution Mode"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW9) this is kind of expected:

> ...they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is explicitly scanning for them.

Is there any way to have a macOS app discover peripherals even when they're backgrounded? I'm sure the code I've written is correct because it's the same across iOS and macOS.

### Update 1

I believe that this might be possible just unsure how to approach the issue. Using Apple's Bluetooth Explorer on macOS, I am able to find the desired device AND I'm able to see and read data for my custom service.

This finding is validated from logs from my iOS device about the read requests which are from my `peripheralManager(CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveRead: CBATTRequest)`.

Comment: Does the iOS device you are able to connect to have the same iCloud login as the Mac?  This can (positively) affect the ability of the Mac to connect to it

Comment: @Paulw11 yes it does!